# Simple recurrence in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, recurrence

Simple RecurrenceMax. Score 0

> Our hero - Alex has been working on a research for a week. And he has
>   recently gotten a recurrence relation for solving a part of that
>   research. But he has no time. Could you do it?
>
> Recurrence relation is as follows : f(n) = 3 * f(n-1) + 2 * f(n-2) + 2
>   * g(n-1)+3 * g(n-2) , g(n) = g(n-1) + 2 * g(n-2).
>
> You are given the initial value of f(1), f(0), g(1), g(0).
>
> You have to output f(N) mod 10^9.

Input:

> In the first line you are given 4 numbers : f(1), f(0), g(1), g(0)
>   respectively.  In the next line you are given an integer N.

Output:

> Output f(N) mod 10^9.

Constraints:

> 1 <= f(0),f(1),g(0),g(1) <= 10
>   1 <= N <= 10^18

Sample Input (Plaintext Link)

> 1 1 1 1
>   4
>   Sample Output (Plaintext Link)
>   162

This is indeed a very easy question. I simply used iteration with 6 variables f0, f1, f2, g0, g1, g2 to solve it. In the loop, I first compute g2, f2, then f0=f1, f1=f2, g0=g1, g1=g2. The data types are unsigned long long in c++.

However, the time limit is 1 second and I get 1.06 second. Therefore I passed only one test case in the test, others "time limit exceeded". Is there any faster way to solve it?

my code is:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace sdt;

int main()
{
    unsigned long long f0, f1, g0, g1, f2, g2;
    unsigned long long N;
    cin>>f1>>f0>>g1>>g0;
    cin>>N;
    for(unsigned long long i=2; i<N+1; i++)
    {
        f2=3*f1+2*f0+2*g1*3*g0;
        g2=g1+2*g0;
        f0=f1;
        f1=f2;
        g0=g1;
        g1=g2;
    }
    unsigned long long result=f2%1000000000;
    cout<<result;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `Is there any faster way to solve it?` Yes, forget the recursive equations. Do some manual calculation to get a linear one.

Comment: You will be more likely to get help if you post your code.

Comment: Hi, I have added my code, thanks for your reminder

Comment: This code doesn't give the right result for the sample input

Answer (score 2):

Given recurrence can be written as

[image]

with the base conditions given by `f(1)`, `f(o)`, `g(1)` and `g(0)`. Now, to calculate `f(n)`, we have to raise the coefficient matrix to the power `n - 1`. Fortunately, this can be done using  `log(n)` matrix multiplications. This is a famous problem of [exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation).

Since matrix size is small, this has `O(log(n))` complexity.

Answer (score 1):

1-The code is different from the recurrence relation. The code should be:

```
f2=3*f1+2*f0+2*g1+3*g0;
```

2-One possible way to optimize the code is to decrease the number of heavy calculations, which is the multiplication in this case, by doing this:

```
f2=3*(f1+g0)+2*(f0+g1);
```

However, I think the compiler's optimizer will do this automatically for you, but you can try yourself to be sure.